# How to find positive solution by using LSQR method?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve the unsymmetric equation $AX=B$.

$A$ is an $8\times10$ matrix, $X$ and $B$ are both $10\times1$ matrices.

But the solution $x$ is a capacitance; it is a positive value.

A negative value is impossible.

If I use [this matlab function](http://www.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/cgls.html)...

It will sometime give me negative value solutions, depending on the initial point I choose.

Is there any way that I can change the algorithm make it find positive values only?

Or is there another numerical method that can let me get the positive solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve a *non-negative least squares* problem:

$$\min_x \|Ax-b\|^2\qquad \textrm{s.t.}\qquad x\geq 0.$$

A solution exists to your original problem if and only if the solution $\tilde{x}$ of this NNLS problem has residual $\|A\tilde{x}-b\|^2=0$. If $\|A\tilde{x}-b\|^2 > 0$, there is no positive solution to your original problem.

Note that since your system is underconstrained, it is possible that your problem has infinitely many positive solutions. Most NNLS codes will only find one.

If you are using Matlab, take a look at the function `lsqnonneg`. Good, free C implementations of NNLS are surprisingly hard to come by, but BCLS (http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mpf/bcls/) will work in a pinch.